# Query based on bearing movements - How many shifts they worked?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im working in a company where the colleagues in manufacturing are working in shifts. The shifting-system could be every month different. So its possible that the guys work one week only at Night, but next week Early, Late and Night.

Now I have a database, where i can see, what the colleagues have produced each and every day. Basically, i can see just the bearing movements. Theoretically, i can now say "ok, on 2017-04-27 they worked in 3 shifts, because there weare bearing movements in between 6:00am - 2:00pm, 2:00pm - 10:00pm and 10:00pm - 6:00am this day". There are hundreds of bearing movements each hour.

What i want to do now is: I want to find out, how many shifts the guys have been working each Month. So best result would be if i can get a query, which gives me the Monthnumber and next column the amounts of shifts for this month.

I guess the query has to check each day of the Month and check if there are entry for each possible shift, if so, than count a counter or something.

Table-Schema:

```
TABLE_NAME lb
COLUMN_NAME      DATA_TYPE
id               int
date_            datetime
time_            time
doc              varchar
pgroup           int
piece            varchar
amount           decimal
name1            varchar
name2            varchar
name3            varchar
storage_location int
bs               varchar
hash             varchar
inserted         datetime
edited           datetime
```

Sample Data (only from Column ID, date_, time_)

```
ID   date_                      time_
1   2017-02-06 00:00:00.000    10:05:34.0000000
2   2017-02-02 00:00:00.000    09:15:31.0000000
3   2017-02-02 00:00:00.000    16:19:12.0000000
4   2017-01-30 00:00:00.000    14:15:01.0000000
5   2017-01-30 00:00:00.000    21:35:10.0000000
6   2017-01-31 00:00:00.000    05:33:20.0000000
7   2017-01-31 00:00:00.000    05:36:07.0000000
8   2017-01-31 00:00:00.000    14:33:56.0000000
9   2017-01-30 00:00:00.000    06:25:25.0000000
10  2017-01-30 00:00:00.000    10:05:29.0000000
11  2017-01-30 00:00:00.000    15:25:26.0000000
12  2017-01-30 00:00:00.000    17:35:29.0000000
13  2017-01-30 00:00:00.000    21:05:26.0000000
14  2017-01-31 00:00:00.000    00:45:44.0000000
15  2017-01-30 00:00:00.000    08:15:25.0000000
16  2017-01-30 00:00:00.000    10:05:32.0000000
17  2017-01-30 00:00:00.000    15:25:29.0000000
18  2017-01-30 00:00:00.000    17:35:32.0000000
19  2017-01-30 00:00:00.000    21:05:30.0000000
20  2017-01-31 00:00:00.000    00:45:53.0000000
```

Output based on the sample data:

```
month   shifts
2       3
1       4
```

Is this possible?

Comment: show table schema.. also sample data and desired output

Comment: It all depend upon table structure and some data.how you storing Shift,datetime and other details ?system must have Shift Master and ShiftID must be store in attendance table.so this query is easy.

Comment: Added some more informations

Comment: How would you determine the number of shifts? Are all employees in a shit checking in and out at exactly the same time?

Comment: No, this doesnt matter. This data has nothing to do with the checking in of the employees.

I just need a counter which does the Following 

---> for every day of the month

go through all day of that month, look up, if there is at least one entry which is inbetween 6am and 2pm, then count+1, if there is at least one entry which is between 2pm and 10pm, then count+1, if there is at least one entry which is between 10pm and 6am, then count+1. Do this for every day of the Month. Print out the Month number and the Counter.

Comment: Does the shift that starts Jan 31 at 10 and end on Feb 1 at 6 count for both months?

Comment: @GuillaumeCR No, it counts for that month when the shift starts, so in this example the shift starts Jan 31 at 10, so it counts for Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
SELECT monthday AS "month", COUNT(monthday) AS "shifts" FROM
  (SELECT date_trunc( 'month', date ) FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM lb 
       WHERE '06:00:00'::time <= time AND time < '14:00:00'::time
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT DISTINCT date FROM lb 
       WHERE '14:00:00'::time <= time AND time < '22:00:00'::time
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT DISTINCT date FROM lb 
       WHERE '22:00:00'::time <= time AND time < '06:00:00'::time
    ) shiftdays
  ) monthdays (monthday) GROUP BY monthday;
```

(i did not have to time to check if it is syntactically correct, for mobile reasons).
Also, this is PostgreSQL Syntax, adapt it to your SQL Dialect.

**How does it work?**
This piece selects all days during the first shift. Each day only once (DISTINCT).

```
SELECT DISTINCT date FROM lb 
  WHERE '06:00:00'::time <= time AND time < '14:00:00'::time
```

The same for the other shifts.
Then the days of these three shifts are thrown into the same bowl.
If you throw the same day in twice, it's in the bowl twice too (UNION ALL; i don't want to say group, because the GROUP already has a different meaning in SQL).

Now we have days for all possible days of the year (or at least all days rows in the table). Each day appears `0 <= n <= 3` times to count at most 3 shifts per day represented by 3 days in the temporary table.

Now we go from the days like '2017-01-15' to the month (with day = 01 each) by using `date_trunc( 'month', date )`.
We can only do this now, because if we try it earlier, then we cannot prevent more than three shifts per day, which are represented by at most three DAYS in the imaginary bowl.

And finally, now that we have the days aligned to months, we can group by and use `count(*) = shifts`.
The table aliases `shiftdays` and `monthdays` are required, lest the DBMS complaineth.

Use date_trunc( 'day', date ) to get rid of any seconds in your datetime (if necessary, not shown above; if you have milliseconds not 0000 in your datetime).
Use date_trunc( 'month', date ) to reduce all days to their month, then count them.
Make sure you have an index on columns (time, date) (in this order; time needs to be used with ranges <= and <; and datetime on the same index to be INDEX ONLY SCAN because you don't want the DMBS to go load tuples with 10 columns from the heap).
Three index only scans for the three shifts should be fine.
A full table scan will probably be not acceptable.
You can also mix in some `WHERE` clauses to just get the shifts-count for a single month, i.e. `WHERE '2017-01-01' <= date AND date < '2017-02-01'`. With an index on (date, time) that should be quite quick.
Note also the left inclusive ranges above (l <= date AND date < without = r).

So yeah, it's possible. Adapt it, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks! Will test it after the weekend1

Comment: Thank you! Changed it a bit and its working like charm!